# Why is WebStorm expecting my manifest.json file to be SAP Fiori related?

Tags: sapui5, webstorm

I am using WebStorm to program a Chrome plugin. This requires a `manifest.json`file.

For some reason, WebStorm thinks that the manifest file belong to a SAP Fiori project and gives me a warning. It tells me that properties like `sap.app` and `sap.ui` are missing.

[image]

I have never ever worked on an SAP project, and never installed any SAP related plugins.

Why is SAP support enabled by default and how can I disable the SAP support in my WebStorm environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't happen to me.

Anyway, you can change the schema used for current file by choosing appropriate schema from a dropdown in the status bar in the lower right corner, or create a new schema mapping:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the dropdown list. Changing it to JSON-schema-7 fixed it.

Comment: @Waruyama You can select "Web App Manifest"